# Adding referenced values within the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the data I am working with:

Table: CUSTOMERS

```
   ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  CATEGORY  SPONSORID BALANCE_DUE
```

---

```
 10001 Rita       Rush       MEMBER                     8.25
 10002 Becky      Finch      MEMBER                     3.75
 10003 Joyce      Wilson     FRIEND        10002          20
 10004 Carol      Crane      FRIEND        10002          10
 10005 Tricia     Tatum      MEMBER
 10006 Lucy       Nash       MEMBER                     1.75
 10007 Larry      Bell       FRIEND        10001
 10008 Ron        Welsh      FRIEND        10009
```

I would like some guidance/helpful hints for a query that displays MEMBER and the sum of their balance + the balance of their FRIEND. Keep in mind that SPONSORID references ID.

It should end up looking something along these lines:

```
    ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  BALANCE_DUE
```

---

```
 10001 Rita       Rush              8.25
 10002 Becky      Finch            33.75
 10006 Lucy       Nash              1.75
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Kindly share desired result

Comment: So sorry, just added that in!

Comment: Does this need to be recursive? That is: Can Larry Bell, who is sponsored by Rita Rush, sponsor others himself? And if that was the case, would those amounts due need to be aggregated up to Rita, or only up to Larry? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT CUSTOMERS.ID member_id, (CUSTOMERS.BALANCE_DUE + sponsor_sums.balance_sum) total_balance_due
FROM CUSTOMERS,
(SELECT SPONSORID, SUM(BALANCE_DUE) balance_sum
FROM CUSTOMERS
WHERE CATEGORY = 'FRIEND'
GROUP BY SPONSORID) AS 'sponsor_sums'
WHERE CUSTOMERS.CATEGORY = 'MEMBER'
AND CUSTOMERS.ID = sponsor_sums.SPONSORID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 `cte`(Common Table Expressions) to extract `member` and `FRIEND` aggregate records from table and joining the 2 cte's to get you desired result as below.

```
with cte1 as 
(select * from table1
 where CATEGORY = 'MEMBER'
 ),
 cte2 as
 (select SPONSORID, sum(BALANCE_DUE) as BALANCE_DUE 
  from table1
  where CATEGORY = 'FRIEND'
  group by SPONSORID
  )

select t1.Id, 
       t1.First_Name, 
       t1.Last_Name, 
       t1.BALANCE_DUE + coalesce(t2.BALANCE_DUE,0)  as BALANCE_DUE
from cte1 t1
left join cte2 t2
on t1.id = t2.SponsorId
order by t1.Id;
```

**OR**  *derived tables as below:*

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.FIRST_NAME,
  t1.LAST_NAME,
  t1.BALANCE_DUE + COALESCE(t2.BALANCE_DUE, 0) AS BALANCE_DUE
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM table1
      WHERE CATEGORY = 'MEMBER') t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SPONSORID, BALANCE_DUE
           FROM table1
           WHERE CATEGORY = 'FRIEND'
           GROUP BY SPONSORID) t2
ON t1.id = t2.SponsorId
ORDER BY t1.Id
```

**Result:**

```
+-------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|  ID   | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | BALANCE_DUE |
+-------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| 10001 | Rita       | Rush      | 8.25        |
| 10002 | Becky      | Finch     | 33.75       |
| 10005 | Tricia     | Tatum     | NULL        |
| 10006 | Lucy       | Nash      | 1.75        |
+-------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90ee0/20)**